# flutter build apk --debug failing to build debug without release keystore

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

My Flutter app is failing to build a debug version. I built release with the signing keys just fine, but now trying to build debug it is looking for the storeFile (which is not there because I've taken the code to another machine without the keys). I'm building running:

```
   flutter build apk --debug
```

but it fails with

> Error running Gradle: ProcessException: Process
>   ...\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where: Build file ...\android\app\build.gradle' **line: 54**
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. path
>   may not be null or empty string. path='null'

line 54 is in the release for the signing configs

```
   storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
```

Shouldn't **--debug** ignore this? Why is it trying to get to that file when this is a debug build?

Here's the build.gradle file w/ the release commented out so I can build debug w/o the keystore:

```
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.6'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
   if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
       keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
   }

   android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myproduct"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

//    signingConfigs {
//       release {
//          keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
//          keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
//          storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
//          storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
//       }
//    }
//    buildTypes {
//       release {
//          signingConfig signingConfigs.release

//             minifyEnabled true
//             useProguard true

//             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//       }
//    }
buildTypes {
       release {
           // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
           // Signing with the debug keys for now,
           // so `flutter run --release` works.
           signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
       }
   }



}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: FYI: here is the signing configs:


   signingConfigs {
      release {
         keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
         keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
         storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
         storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
      }
   }

Comment: What do you have in buildTypes in gradle?

Comment: Hi! Did you create the keystore properties file as specified on the flutter release tutorial? Also, did you add the other variables to the code? You could edit your question and add the full build.gradle file, and tell us where you put the files created on the step by step guide. Best regards.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Yes I followed the instructions in the release tutorial documents but I just can't build a debug version while it's set up with the key file. I've updated the question to include the build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be a head-space error somewhere but I completely removed and reinstalled everything except for Windows, and was back in business. I hate no knowing where this went sideways...